# Delegating access in Google API / Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

So I've got a Python app running which uses a service account in our domain.  This is all working fine, and the service account has been granted access to the correct scope.  I'm using the following which is lifted from one of the Google examples:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

"""Email of the Service Account"""
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'service_account_email@google'

"""Path to the Service Account's Private Key file"""
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_FILE_PATH = 'My Project-xxxxxx.json'

def main():
  scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_FILE_PATH,
            scopes=scopes
        )

  http = httplib2.Http()

  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

  results = service.files().list(
      pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
  items = results.get('files', [])
  if not items:
      print('No files found.')
  else:
      print('Files:')
      for item in items:
          print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This successfully retrieves the documents for the service account.  Now my understanding is that I should be able to delegate access so that I can run as another user.  So I'm adding the following line:

```
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated("user.name@org_domain.org.au")
```

and then using deletegated_credentials when authorizing.  At this point I'm getting the error

> oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied:
>   Requested client not authorized.

So my assumption is that the user that I'm specifying doesn't have access to the API.  Is this the correct approach or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake, posting here for future generations.  My scope in the python code was incorrect, didn't realise it needed to match the scope granted in the admin client **exactly!**

The scope in the admin client is as follows;

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly 
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

and the scope in the code is now;

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

I know I don't need the reports scope, but the point is if they do not match then it won't work.

Rookie mistake!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this post but how do you find the "the scope in the admin client" ? On which page exactly ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Been a while since I looked at this, but I think its under the https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/admin.googleapis.com/overview page in the developer console.